# jquery - $("#myElement").load(url) is not working when being inserted to a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$('#customerPaymentTable > tbody > tr').eq(index).after("<tr><td colspan='6'><center>" + $('#customerRecordForm').load(url) +  "</center></td></tr>");
```

The problem is it returns this value `object Object` instead of the div element. The weird part is if I load the div independently, I mean if I don't insert it in the table row it is working.

The working code is:

```
$('#customerRecordForm').load(url);
```

How am I gonna make it work? I really need that div form to be inserted. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: OMG `<center>`? That's been deprecated for ever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `$('#customerRecordForm').load(url);` will fill the `#customerRecordForm` element with the HTML from the url and then return the jQuery object, not the HTML as a string.

You have two options. Firstly, you could change the logic to get the HTML you require from an AJAX call, and then insert that into the table cell., like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(html){
        $('#customerPaymentTable > tbody > tr').eq(index).after("<tr><td colspan='6'><center>" +  html +  "</center></td></tr>");
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could append the cell, and then call the `load()` on that new element, like this:

```
var $row = $('#customerPaymentTable > tbody > tr').eq(index);
$row.after('<tr><td colspan='6' class="foo"></td></tr>');
$(".foo", $row).load(url);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answering and especially for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using it in some weird way.

you should call the load function on element where you want the loaded data to appear. There is no output value returning from the load(url) function. It just load string from the url and places it into element with ID customerRecordForm

so when you create a

```
<div id="customerRecordForm"></div>
```

then in javascript you'll just call:

```
$('#customerRecordForm').load(url);
```

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

In your example it would be probably something like this:

```
$('#customerPaymentTable > tbody > tr').eq(index).after("<tr><td colspan='6'><div id='customerRecordForm'></div></td></tr>");
$('#customerRecordForm').load(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.load() will not return a valid HTML chunk but a jQuery object. Furthermore, jQuery.load() loads the content asynchronously into the element you call it on. Certainly not what you want...

You will have to inject the html code after the content has loaded.

```
$.get(url, function (response) {
    $('#customerPaymentTable > tbody > tr').eq(index)
        .after("<tr><td colspan='6'><center>" + response +  "</center></td></tr>");

});
```